# Scanning .rar file content entries on multi volume archive

Tags: php, rar

I am playing around with php rar

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.rar.php

Goal : 
Gather file (name) information of multi volume rar archives, from only the first volume.

Example :

Complete volume : 
  **testArchive.rar** ,
  **testArchive.r00**

Available : **testArchive.rar**

Scan files inside archive from testArchive.rar  **WITHOUT** testArchive.r00

Winrar ( rarlabs.com ) gives you the archived (file) content of the multi volume rar archive from the first volume.
Now I want this accomplished by php.

I tried the following but this gives me an empty array.

```
function retnull() { return null; }

$arch = RarArchive::open("testArchive.rar" , NULL , 'retnull' );
$arch->setAllowBroken(true);

if ($arch === FALSE)
    die("Cannot open testArchive.rar");

$entries = $arch->getEntries();
if ($entries === FALSE)
    die("Cannot retrieve entries");

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($entries);
echo '</pre>';
```

I do not need to extract the rar files , but only need the content [NAMES] of the folders/files inside the archive like the program winrar does.

Can somebody give me a hint in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my own problem.

Install UnRar  http://www.win-rar.com/rarextras.html
  ( I am using CentOS  :  **yum install unrar** )

```
   <?php

    $path   ='/path/to/archiveFolder/';
    $archive='testArchive.rar';

    $var =exec('unrar l -p- '.escapeshellarg($path.$archive),$file_output);

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($file_output);
    echo '</pre>';

    ?>
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => UNRAR 4.10 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal
    [2] => 
    [3] => Volume path/to/archiveFolder/testArchive.rar
    [4] => 
    [5] =>  Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
    [6] => -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [7] =>  testfile.mkv 1699997366 49999891  --> 19-02-12 21:05  .....A.   95E20DA9 m0g 2.0
    [8] => -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [9] =>     1       1699997366 49999891   2%       volume 1
    [10] => 
)
```

After that just write a class to retrieve the information you need with reg-patterns or substr.